# How do I draw an image to match the position of a specific text on the page?

Tags: pdf, pdfsharp

I'm struggling to figure out how the text is positioned in my PDF. Stripping unrelated parts (everything else is inside q/BT/ET/Q blocks), I've got this fragment on a page:

```
0.750000 0.000000 0.000000 -0.750000 0.000000 841.920044 cm
q
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 rg
BT
0 Tr
/F1 13.333900 Tf
1 0 0.000000 -1 49.119999 304.799988 Tm
[......] TJ
```

I'm trying to use a `gfx.DrawImage` to put something over it, but the image ends up too low on the page if I use `.DrawImage(foo, 49.12, 304.8, 10, 10)`

The real Y position for that line of text is around 200 (just eyeballing), but how do I arrive at that from the given transformations?

Playing around with the matrices gives me very wrong results.

Comment: *"The real Y position for that line of text is around 200"* - are you sure? Given those instructions it should be 841.920044 - .75 * 304.799988, i.e. approximately 613. Please share the PDF in question.

Comment: @mkl Unfortunately the resulting files are generated full of PII, so I can't share them. But you are right... it seems I'm confused between the pdfsharp and pdf coordinates. PdfSharp's 30 x 200 (which looks almost perfect) results in 30 x 618.2744 coordinates in the document.

Comment: With Adobe Reader you can measure the position of the text on the page and then use PDFsharp to draw at the location you measured.

Comment: @IlikedtheoldStackOverflow unfortunately the location changes between documents, so I have to calculate it by finding the location of a specific phrase automatically.

Comment: Comparing the measured position from Adobe Reader with the numbers given in the PDF should allow you to determine a formula when you do it for several documents.